# Hide class when input value equals given value

Tags: jquery, input, hide

I need to hide a div class when a text input with an id of "acct_tier" has a value of 'standard' (without submitting the input). What I've tried isn't working so far:

HTML

```
<input id='acct_tier' type='text'>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#acct_tier').val('standard')) {
        $('.red').hide();
    });
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#acct_tier').on("change propertychange click keyup input paste", function() {
    var $input = $(this);

    if ($input.val() === 'standard') {
        $(".red").hide();   
    } else {
        $(".red").show(); 
    }
});
```

**Demo:** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3xx15jv/)